# ajaxFileUpload stopped working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

We have implemented the ajaxFileUpload jQuery plugin in our project and has been working till yesterday, when it stopped working in Chrome (version 21.0.1180.79 m).  However it does work in FF and IE browsers.  No code has been modified. Here is the code snippet:

```
$.ajaxFileUpload({
            url: 'AjaxFileUploader.ashx',
            secureuri: false,
            fileElementId: 'upfile',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { name: 'logan', id: 'id' },
            success: function (data, status) {
                PreviewImage(data);
            },
            error: function (data, status, e) {
            }
        });
```

I tried running this through the Chrome developer tool to see if I could see any exception, but had no success.  Can somebody please help?

Comment: Did you reinstall Chrome or change its configuration ?

Comment: No, I did not.  Nothing has changed as far as code goes or any of the tools including Chrome.

Comment: Ugh, I am experiencing the same thing.  It seems that Chrome is dying when it tries to eval valid javascript.  Like you said, it is fine in FF, IE and prior Chrome versions.  Very annoying having to waste so much time trying to work around stuff broken by browser "upgrades"!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> Extensions and disable any strange extensions.  This fixed it for me.

An extension was inserting HTML into the background iframe used by AjaxFileUpload for returning json.  The eval was failing due to the HTML for this element corrupting the json response.

Prior to the Chrome update, everything worked fine so presumably something about this update changed the extension behavior.  Not cool.